# Can Entity Framework handle many to many relationship without an intersection object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

Using database first model: Let's say we have the classic tables `Student`, `Course` and `StudentCourse` (the latter obviously having FKs to `Student` and `Course`).

If you import this model to EF, you will get an object generated for each of them.  The `Student` and `Course` classes will each have a collection of `StudentCourses`, from which you need to jump another relationship to get to the `Course` or `Student`, respectively.

I would like to have the code generated in such a way that the underlying intersection table is invisible, i.e. `Student` has a collection of `Courses`, and `Course` has a collection of `Students`.  I have seen this done in other ORM software (specifically, [TopLink](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/toplink/overview/index.html)).  Can it be done in EF?

Comment: So just exempt the `table1table2` model?

Comment: It's certainly possible with code-first, so I would assume it's possible with database-first.

Comment: Does your `StudentCourses` table have any additional columns? This article seems to suggest you'll get the desired behaviour if it doesn't: http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model/

Comment: @RichardDeeming - Hm, I don't have any other meaningful columns, but I do have a separate autonumbered ID field.  Strictly speaking I could make a composite PK and drop the ID field, if that's necessary...

Comment: From what I've read, dropping that column would work. A composite PK is usually a better choice for this sort of table anyway.

Comment: @RichardDeeming - you're right, it works.  Please put this as an answer so I can give you credit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://learnentityframework.com/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model/), you'll get the desired behaviour if your `StudentCourse` table only contains the foreign-key columns. If it contains any other columns, EF will generate an intermediate entity to represent the join.

In this case, dropping the surrogate key from the `StudentCourse` table and replacing it with a composite primary key should work.

Comment: Basically, anytime you have an extra "attribute" on the relationship, you will get the extra entity in EF.  You just have to think of the surrogate key as an "attribute".  The other side of the coin is that if you want attributes, this extra entity is a musthave.  (Think of Employee to JobTitle relationship, but the ~relationship has a "StartedOnDate" attribute.  Thus you must have this extra entity.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it in EF Code First using ICollections. For example:

```
public class Student 
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        Courses = New HashSet<Course>();
    }
}
```

Repeat for Course and swap it all over. This will create three tables in your database (Student, Course and StudentCourse) with a m-to-m relationship. Most importantly StudentCourse will be an invisible linking table that has no Entity in your model.

Comment: There's a load of scuttlebutt on the web about it. The most useful article I found was this one by [Prashant Brall](http://prashantbrall.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/ef-code-first-managing-relationships/).

Comment: Correct, as long as the ~relationship does not have any extra attributes.  See my comment on the richard-deeming answer.