# How configure many to many relationship without new entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have two tables `Human` and `Pet`. And have table `HumanToPet`.

How in entity framework do it?

example:

```
class Human
{
   string Name;
   virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE** I use mapping (Fluent Configurations)

Comment: Did you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588574/can-entity-framework-handle-many-to-many-relationship-without-an-intersection-ob?

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Human
{
   public Human()
   {
      Pets = new List<Pet>();
   }

   public int HumanID { get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}

public partial class Pet
{
   public Pet()
   {
      Owners= new List<Human>();
   }

   public int PetID { get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Human> Owners { get; set; }
}
```

From this structure EF will be able to infer the relationships.

EDIT: Fluent API mapping:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Human>()
 .HasMany(a => a.Pets)
 .WithMany()
 .Map(x =>
 {
   x.MapLeftKey("HumanID");
   x.MapRightKey("PetID");
   x.ToTable("HumanToPet");
  });
```

Comment: I use fluent configurations and whoud like use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add references between these tables in your database.
After it, your EF model generated in VS will see it.