# Entity Framework not recognizing foreign key

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Here's my table structure:

**Person**

```
PersonID int
```

**Address**

```
AddressId int
Address varchar
```

**PersonAddress**

```
PersonID int primary key references Person.PersonID
AddressID int primary key references Address.AddressID
```

As you can see there is no relation between `Person` and `Address`. When I add these 3 tables to EF 6.0, it does not add the `PersonAddress` table but adds a relationship between `Person` and `Address`. I am deeply confused.

Comment: That's exactly how it's supposed to work in EF, and that's the relationship you're trying to have anyway in objects

Comment: How are you "adding" this to Entity Framework? Are you using code-first? If so, please **show us** your classes! Typically, EF will model the *conceptual* model of a `Person` having multiple addresses, and an `Address` potentially belonging to multiple people - but it'll "hide" the details of how that's handled in the database. No need to be worried!

Comment: @marc_s 
Thanks. I am using database first model. So EF is intelligently assuming that addresses can be shared across persons and one person can have multiple addresses. I thought it will add all the tables I tell it to add and show it in the EDMX diagram. This is totally cool. Any documentation on it? Thanks. I will play with what it generated and see if that satsifies my needs.

Comment: If you have a database model, you should be able to right-click on your design surface and go `Generate Database from Model`. You'll get the SQL that would be used to generate your database - I'm **sure** you'll see that "link" table in there, too!

Comment: Docs: use MSDN and the usual Microsoft Dev Cenver for EF - that's the best docs you can find

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Entity Framework handle many to many relationship without an intersection object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588574/can-entity-framework-handle-many-to-many-relationship-without-an-intersection-ob)

Answer (score 0):

EF is doing exactly what you want. In EF you have a relationship between OBJECTS, not SCHEMA. The object relationship between Person and Address can be accomplished without the need of a third object. This reduces the complexity and makes the code easier to manage. EF will handle translating the relationship back and forth to the schema as needed.